# How do I hide a panel using C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I used Gridview to display data. Under Gridview I had put one label for 'question', four labels for 'options', one label for 'correct answer' and one label for 'explanation' of answer of the question.

Label for correct Answer and explanation is under a panel.
This panel should show when user click on 'show answer' button and hide when again click on that button.
Under page load method I wrote "anspanel.Style.Add("display", "none");" to hide the panel but this line is showing syntax error:-"name 'anspanel' doesn't exist in the current context".
I can't figure out why.

**Here is what I have tried :-**

**.aspx.cs =:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class Student_Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        anspanel.Style.Add("display", "none");
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT top 2 Question, Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4, CorrectAns, Explanation FROM Questions");
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Student_Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentTab = 0;
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            select: function (e, i) {
                currentTab = i.index;
            }
        });
    });
    $("#btnNext").live("click", function () {
        var tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
        var c = $('#tabs').tabs("length");
        currentTab = currentTab == (c - 1) ? currentTab : (currentTab + 1);
        tabs.tabs('select', currentTab);
        $("#btnPrevious").show();
        if (currentTab == (c - 1)) {
            $("#btnNext").hide();
        } else {
            $("#btnNext").show();
        }
    });
    $("#btnPrevious").live("click", function () {
        var tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
        var c = $('#tabs').tabs("length");
        currentTab = currentTab == 0 ? currentTab : (currentTab - 1);
        tabs.tabs('select', currentTab);
        if (currentTab == 0) {
            $("#btnNext").show();
            $("#btnPrevious").hide();
        }
        if (currentTab < (c - 1)) {
            $("#btnNext").show();
        }
    });

    $(function () {
        //$("#Panel2").hide();
        document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit = function () {
            return false;
        }//Avoid Reloading
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            if ($('#anspanel').is(":hidden")) {
                $('#anspanel').show();
       
            }
            else {
                $('#anspanel').hide();
            }

            if ($("#Button1").val() == "Show Answer") {
                $("#Button1").val("Hide Answer");
            } else {
                $("#Button1").val("Show Answer");
            }
       

        });
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


        <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Tab 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Tab 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
           <span>A-</span> <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option1")%>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>B-</span> <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option2")%>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>C-</span> <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option3")%>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>D-</span> <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option4")%>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbs<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Answer"  />
            <br />

            <asp:Panel id="anspanel" runat="server">

                <span>Correct Answer is :-</span><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CorrectAns")%>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Explanation")%>'></asp:Label>


            </asp:Panel>


        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <br />

                 </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

          </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        Tab 2 Content
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        Tab 3 Content
    </div>
     <div id="tabs-4">
        Tab 4 Content
    </div>
     <div id="tabs-5">
        Tab 5 Content
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnPrevious" value="Previous" style = "display:none"/>
<input type="button" id="btnNext" value="Next" />

    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please show me where I am making mistake and what is the solution.

error :-

```html
Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 24:                     Panel panel1 = (Panel)GridView1.FindControl("Panel1");
Line 25:                     Panel anspanel = (Panel)GridView1.FindControl("anspanel");
Line 26:                     anspanel.Style.Add("display", "none");
Line 27:                 }
Line 28:             }

Source File: e:\Way2Success\Student\Test.aspx.cs    Line: 26 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Student_Test.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Way2Success\Student\Test.aspx.cs:26
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2952
```

Comment: You Panel `anspanel` is inside a GirdView and therefore it can't be accessed directly in codebehind file. You need to first access the Panel using this FindControl method like this `Panel anspanel = (Panel)GridView1.FindControl("anspanel");` and then apply the desired styling on this control

Comment: Also you wrote in your script `$('#anspanel')`. I think this won't work as well since your Panel is inside GridView and hence your Panel's ID will be changed after rendering into HTML. It would become `GridView1_anspanel` You need to reconfirm it

Comment: I just realized that your Panel `anspanel` is inside another Panel which is inside a GridView. So you eventually first need to find the first Panel control `Panel1` inside GridView and then find the desired Panel `anspanel` within the `Panel1`

Comment: @sohaiby Panel panel1 = (Panel)GridView1.FindControl("Panel1");
            Panel Anspanel = (Panel)panel1.FindControl("anspanel");
            Anspanel.Style.Add("display", "none");   .......is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to bind your grid, otherwise there won't be any Rows/Controls in there. Then you have to find your desired control and tweak it's properties

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   GridView1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT top 2 Question, Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4, CorrectAns, Explanation FROM Questions");
   GridView1.DataBind();
   foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
   {
      if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
         Panel panel1 = (Panel)row.FindControl("Panel1");
         Panel anspanel = (Panel)panel1.FindControl("anspanel");
         anspanel.Style.Add("display", "none");
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Check this answer again. On your line 25, change `(Panel)GridView1.FindControl("anspanel");` to `(Panel)panel1.FindControl("anspanel");`

Comment: Same error occur on this line :- '(Panel)panel1.FindControl("anspanel");'  Is it because of applying jquery on panel and button which is placed under gridview???

Comment: Are you binding your grid before applying the styling? Check my answer, you must first bind your grid then you can add the style

Comment: I did as you suggested then also same error is coming

Comment: Apologies mate.. I made a mistake in my code. I've corrected it. On your line 24, it's `Panel panel1 = (Panel)row.FindControl("Panel1");` Use `row` instead of `GridView1`

Comment: Finally, no error and the data is successfully displayed..but my `Show Answer` (Button1) button is not working. When I click on it, it is not showing `anspanel`